# Chilkat [CkHttp] delphi memory leak

Tags: http, chilkat

Using the last version of chilkat 9.5.0.0

Same problem from this topic 
http://www.chilkatforum.com/questions/8569/delphi-http-memory-leak-with-getquickstr

Im using threads and memory leak is extreme!!

This code doesn't solve the problem.

`CkHttp_ClearBgEventLog(HttClient);`

`CkHttp_CloseAllConnections(HttClient);`

Tried to create and dispose component every iteration and same after every "get" or "post" request after using these methods:

`CkHttp_PostUrlEncoded()`

`CkHttp__quickGetStr()`

But, nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

The ClearBgEventLog method is part of a set of "background/async" methods and properties for the HTTP class that have long ago been deprecated and will be removed.

You should instead use the Async methods where the Async version of the method ends in "Async" and returns a Task object.  For example, QuickGetAsync.

Comment: Tried to use async methods but memory leak is more than was before.
In debbuger i got that https://imgur.com/O26557t

Comment: Maybe exists another solutions?
@Matt